# Prevent Route Change Based on Routing Parameters in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've searched all over for this. I basically want to be able to read the routing parameters collection and cancel the route if a certain parameter is missing. Using prevent default in $routeChangeStart does not work. It works in $locationChangeStart although this callback doesn't provide you with a routing parameters collection.

**Is there a way I can check for a routing parameter and if it is missing cancel the route?**

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    // no route parameters... booo
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    if (!($.isNumeric(next.params.siteId) && +next.params.siteId)) {
        event.preventDefault(); // this doesn't work
        $location.url('home');
    }
});
```

I've seen some hacks in other posts but they all seem specific to ngRoute. I am using angular routing segment though.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question but I just passed through the same situation and here is how I addressed:

```js
...
,onEnter: function($state, $stateParams) {
   if ($stateParams.id=='') { //or whatever constraint
     $state.go(<any other route>);
     return;
   }
 },
...
```